# Which of the following operations is functionally complete?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Which of the following operations is functionally complete ?

Consider the operations

$\textit{f (X, Y, Z) = X'YZ + XY' + Y'Z'}$ and $\textit{g (X, Y, Z) = X'YZ + X'YZ' + XY}$

---

Is there Any technique to approach such questions ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to convert the function into a nand or a nor function. If it gets converted then it is functionally complete.

The first function we have is $$f(X,Y,Z)=X'YZ+XY'+Y'Z'\tag{1.}$$
How equation 1 can be converted into $Y'Z'$ 
.
Put $X=0$ $\to f=YZ+Y'Z'$
multiply by Y' then $f.Y'=Y'Z' \tag{2.}$
from equation 2 ,it is clear that if we can get complement of $Y'$ and $AND$ function from function $f$ then we can get Nor function also.

Put $Y=Z=1 \to f=X'$ put $X=Y$ so $f=Y'$. Put $Y=1, X=X'$
 in $f\to f=XZ$ that's how we get both AND and NOT function to eventually get every other function.
Similarly try with other function.